# MSBuild - one Package Reference interferes with loading a separate Task

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget-package, msbuild-task

Using MSBuild, the following builds and works fine:

```
<PackageReference Include="Publicise.MSBuild.Task" Version="1.3.0"/>

<Target Name="Publicise" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
  <Publicise
    AssemblyPath="..."
    OutputPath="../"/>
</Target>
```

However, when I add another Package Reference (changing nothing else), it encounters errors on build:

```
<PackageReference Include="Publicise.MSBuild.Task" Version="1.3.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="ILRepack.MSBuild.Task" Version="2.0.13"/>
```

This results in error MSB4062:

The "Publicise" task could not be loaded from the assembly ...\ILRepack.MSBuild.Task.dll.  Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Why is something completely separate preventing the task from being properly found, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by these two msbuild task nuget packages accidentally.

**And** since you have installed the `ILRepack.MSBuild.Task` nuget package at the end. And the **PackageReference** node of `ILRepack.MSBuild.Task` is akways at the end. So `$(TaskAssembly)` is always loads from `ILRepack.MSBuild.Task` nuget package and the value from `publicise.msbuild.task` is being covered. And the issue `The "Publicise" task could not be loaded from the assembly ILRepack.MSBuild.Task.dll` makes sense.

`C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\publicise.msbuild.task\1.3.0\build\Publicise.MSBuild.Task.props`

[image]

`C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\ilrepack.msbuild.task\2.0.13\build\ILRepack.MSBuild.Task.props`

[image]

**Also**, when you project loads the nuget package, you can check under `C:\xxx\source\repos\xxx(project_name)\xxx(project_name)\obj\xxx.csproj.nuget.g.props`:

[image]

Loading the `ILRepack.MSBuild.Task.props` is always at the end and `$(TaskAssembly)` is always from `ilrepack.msbuild.task` due to being overwritten by the later installed package.

The error `Publicise` task(should be from `publicise.msbuild.task`) from `ilrepack.msbuild.task` could be understood.

**Solution**

**So** you should make `publicise.msbuild.task` at the end.

**Solution 1)**

open `C:\xxx\source\repos\xxx(project_name)\xxx(project_name)\obj\xxx.csproj.nuget.g.props` file,

modify like this:

```
<ImportGroup Condition=" '$(ExcludeRestorePackageImports)' != 'true' ">
   
 <Import Project="$(NuGetPackageRoot)ilrepack.msbuild.task\2.0.13\build\ILRepack.MSBuild.Task.props" Condition="Exists('$(NuGetPackageRoot)ilrepack.msbuild.task\2.0.13\build\ILRepack.MSBuild.Task.props')" />

 <Import Project="$(NuGetPackageRoot)publicise.msbuild.task\1.3.0\build\Publicise.MSBuild.Task.props" Condition="Exists('$(NuGetPackageRoot)publicise.msbuild.task\1.3.0\build\Publicise.MSBuild.Task.props')" />
</ImportGroup>
```

make `Publicise.MSBuild.Task.props` at the buttom.

Then, save the changes and then click **Build** button rather than **Rebuild** button to test again.

**Solution 2)**

downgrade `ILRepack.MSBuild.Task` nuget package to version `2.0.0`.

===============================

**Update 1**

Thanks for sharing your opinion about the workaround. Since these two nuget packages have to be used in your project, so these two solutions might not be very useful.

The error, conflict is caused by the author of the nuget packages and incidentally, you're using the same `TaskAssembly` property from  these two nuget packages at the same time.

`TreatAsLocalProperty="TaskAssembly"` will not solve the issue. `<packages_id>.props` files from the nuget packages are still embedded in the project's CSPROj file. Whether the fields are the same as TaskAssembly or will conflict.

The better solution is that you should rename one of the `TaskAssembly` of the nuget packages to another, which would not cause conflict.

**1)** Open `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\ilrepack.msbuild.task\2.0.13\build\ILRepack.MSBuild.Task.props` file:

change `TaskAssembly` property to another like `TaskAssembly_copy`:

[image]

Comment: Hello, this is a decent start, however neither of these solutions fully work for me.

I can't just change the order in the .csproj.nuget.g.props file because there is also an ILRepack task.

I can't just downgrade ILREpack.MSBuild.Tasks to 2.0.0 because it is not compatible with net40 which I must use.

To be clear, the issue is caused by both projects sharing the same `TaskAssembly` property?  Why doesn't `TreatAsLocalProperty="TaskAssembly"` prevent this issue?  Would forking one of these and altering that property name be a viable solution?

Comment: I have updated my answer and you can check `update 1`.